# How to change the color of text and svg picture together with css?

Tags: css

I have svg and text snippet:

```css
svg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
svg:hover {
  fill: red !important;
}

div > svg.icon:hover circle,
div > svg.icon:hover path {
  stroke: red;
}

.custom-fill:hover {
  color:red;
}


body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  place-items: center center;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <a>
              <div class="custom-fill">
                <div>
                  <svg class="icon" id="6a8da56c-64cb-4c0d-b7e3-2b80c0db2d07" data-name="ICON" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="192" height="192" viewBox="0 0 192 192"><circle id="3ad8aabf-2066-47d6-9a2f-c027e5c19606" data-name="&lt;Pfad&gt;" cx="96" cy="63.91" r="36.09" fill="none" stroke="#333" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/><path id="243fad7b-53d4-4daa-93b6-31f40d832ead" data-name="&lt;Pfad&gt;" d="M156,164.1c-6.48-43.88-33.17-64.23-59.64-64.23S42.49,120.21,36,164.09" fill="none" stroke="#333" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/><rect width="192" height="192" fill="none"/></svg>
                </div>
                <label class="iconLabel"> This is a text </label>
              </div>
            </a>
</div>
```

What I need to do is to change the color of the image and the text together. As you can notice it works when I hover on the image (image and text changes color), but when I hover on the text, just only text has changed the color (**image not**).

Could someone help me to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently assign the `:hover` selector on the `svg` element itself. Just assign it to the container `custom-fill` and it will work.

```css
svg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
div.custom-fill:hover {
  color: red;
}
div.custom-fill:hover circle,
div.custom-fill:hover path {
  stroke: red;
}


body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  place-items: center center;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <a>
              <div class="custom-fill">
                <div>
                  <svg class="icon" id="6a8da56c-64cb-4c0d-b7e3-2b80c0db2d07" data-name="ICON" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="192" height="192" viewBox="0 0 192 192"><circle id="3ad8aabf-2066-47d6-9a2f-c027e5c19606" data-name="&lt;Pfad&gt;" cx="96" cy="63.91" r="36.09" fill="none" stroke="#333" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/><path id="243fad7b-53d4-4daa-93b6-31f40d832ead" data-name="&lt;Pfad&gt;" d="M156,164.1c-6.48-43.88-33.17-64.23-59.64-64.23S42.49,120.21,36,164.09" fill="none" stroke="#333" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/><rect width="192" height="192" fill="none"/></svg>
                </div>
                <label class="iconLabel"> This is a text </label>
              </div>
            </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the mistake, works like a charm.